# Host MVC app on Azure Service Fabric

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, azure-service-fabric

Looking into options for starting the migration of an existing application with both MVC web pages and Web Api components to Service Fabric.
We have gotten the Web Api components running under ServiceFabric, but not the MVC web pages.
Based on what little I have seen out there, there does not seem to be a definitive way to run an existing MVC application under service fabric.  Is this correct or am I missing something?
NOTE - by MVC app, I mean a web site built using MVC 6, not Web API services.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't MVC6 the same as ASP NET Core?
And in service fabric there is support to host net core apps. You might need to port the controlls, but it should be straight forward in that case...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can take an MVC 6 application and run it on Service Fabric. Here is an example from the official Azure Sample gallery: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-iot/tree/master/src/Iot.Tenant.WebService

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to develop new application then you can follow below link [service-fabric-add-a-web-frontend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-add-a-web-frontend)

IF you have an existing application you and you don't want to change any code you can deploy your application as Guest executable. follow below link [service-fabric-deploy-existing-app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app)

If you have an existing application (MVC 5 and IIS based) and you want to deploy in Service Fabric you and host with help of container. MVC5 app does not support self-host and tightly coupled with IIS. check below link [iis-based-applications-to-service-fabric-using-docker-container](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/monub/2017/06/28/docker-blog-series-part-3-deploy-iis-based-applications-to-service-fabric-using-docker-containers/)